# Is there any way to suppress the background speech recognition functions and run smoothly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, speech-recognition

I am using trying to develop a program in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. I finally got it to run, although it is a bit temperamental (sometimes it runs smoothly and sometimes it doesn't). 
I have realized that there is no way for it to run without enabling speech recognition, which I turn on before I debug it, although I have found that the background functions of speech recognition interfere with the execution of my code. It starts trying to insert words into my code, which interrupts it and so on. Is there a way to suppress these background functions so that the speech recognition (SR) is focused solely on running my code?

I think the general idea is to find a configuration that will help it run smoothly consistently...

Comment: We use tags on [SO] to organize questions. You don't need to put "Speech Recognition C# Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7" in your titles.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` instead of the `SpeechRecognizer`

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
namespace speectest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        GrammarBuilder grandma = new GrammarBuilder();
        engine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        grandma.AppendDictation();
        engine.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(grandma));
        engine.RecognizeCompleted += new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(engine_RecognizeCompleted);
        engine.RecognizeAsync();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    static void engine_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but this looks like C++...is it? I tried using the speech recognition engine in c# but it doesn't run at all...not even the speech synthesis part of my program I put as checks.

Comment: No, it's C#; certainly not C++. You don't see any #include statements in here.